# why use "use -elf" the result return username with "systemd+"?

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu

when I use docker run -itd mysql,then to use ps -elf check the process infomation with "4 S systemd+  257584  257561  1  80   0 - 712611 poll_s Jul17 ?       00:40:16 mysqld".

```
root@xx:/proc/257584/ns# ps -elf | grep mysqld
4 S systemd+  257584  257561  1  80   0 - 712611 poll_s Jul17 ?       00:40:20 mysqld
root@xx:/proc/257584/ns# ps -el | grep mysqld
4 S   999  257584  257561  1  80   0 - 712611 poll_s ?       00:40:21 mysqld
```

But I use "cat /cat/passwd" can't find username equal to "systemd+".

docker Version: 20.10.12

os  ubuntu20.04

Comment: While your task in general might be programming-related, this questions isn't really. It seems more fit for [the Unix & Linux SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) instead.

Answer (score 3):

`ps` (sadly) trims the username to 8 (if i'm counting right) characters and adds a `+` after the user name initial part. The username could be `systemd-mysql` or `systemd-something` that you can find in passwd.

From manual:

> If the length of the username is greater than the length of the display column, the username will be truncated.  See the -o and -O formatting options to customize length